# Do triplestores use or need indexes?

Tags: indexing, sparql, rdf, triplestore

Some NoSQL databases use indexes. Triplestores too? If yes, how to make or manage them?

I've used Virtuoso and Blazegraph and I suppose is strictly dependent on the database architecture. There isn't any standardization regarding indexing?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no indexing standard for any database. Most RDF databases usually use some indexes based in subject `s`, predicate `p`, and object `o` which in fact are the main parts of any RDF triple `s p o`. And most triple stores use several permutations of those as index, i.e. `spo`, `pos`, `ops`, ...

Comment: Thanks @AKSW. So as far as you know RDF databases don't include the possibility to have an index with a particular subject or predicate? That's my doubt.

Comment: An SPO index would usually be sorted and mean that S??, SP? and SPO can be looked up so it can yield all the triples with a given subject.

Comment: @Alessio Not sure what you mean, but I was saying that there are usually the standard indexes for RDF triples, that do it for the permutations of the RDF triple elements. If the SPARQL query triple pattern just contains the subject, the `SPO` index would be used. If there are subject and predicate given, again the `SPO` index would be used. And so on and so furth...

Answer (score 1):

**User defined** indexes aren't really in the spirit of a triple store. Since all information is managed at the most atomic level possible, every possible access path into the information should have the same conceptual cost.

Compare this with a relational model where one makes explicit decisions about degree of normalization and implicit trade-offs of access performance, compensated with user defined indexes.

This doesn't mean there are no indexes in a triple store. On the contrary, all non trivial implementations use them, whether a spo/pos/ops form or maybe something based on Lucene.

Comment: There's some nice description of the data structures (including brief description of indexing strategy) used in Jena for reference. https://jena.apache.org/documentation/tdb/architecture.html